# SQL Server 2005 Convert Ascii to Unicode (UTF-8 -> nvarchar)

Tags: database, t-sql, unicode

I have data in an nvarchar field with data in ascii format: "Zard FrÃ¨res Guesta"

How do I convert it to a readable(unicode) format in t-sql?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62406 has a function that will do this:

```
select dbo.utf8_to_utf16('Zard FrÃ¨res Guesta')
```

Results:

```
Zard Frères Guesta
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that you have what should be the two bytes of a single unicode character in two consecutive unicode characters (the high bytes are probably all 0 bytes).  This can happen for all sorts of reasons if you aren't handling the code pages correctly during insertions.

You'll need to get these back to single bytes and then re-encode the data.

Comment: The values are stored in a text file in that format(e.g. Zard FrÃ¨res Guesta) and I am using a bulk insert with openrowset to import the data.

Comment: select somecolofdata
   from OPENROWSET(BULK  ''' + @filePath + '\' + @fileName +''',
     FORMATFILE=''' + @formatFileName + ''',
     ERRORFILE =''' + @errorFileName + ''' ,
     FIRSTROW = 2,     
     CODEPAGE = 1252,     
     MAXERRORS = 1000
    ) as importeddata

Comment: This is the format file entry:  
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="500" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>

Comment: <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="somcolofdata" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>

Comment: I am storing it as nvarchar(500)

Comment: @Guazz Is this (Ã¨) meant to be two bytes for a single character (code-point)?  Because then that's not code page 1252 (which is a single byte encoding).

Comment: @Guazz If this is UTF-8 (varying widths, with ASCII as a subset), then BCP can't handle that code page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: How can I tell if it's UTF-8 or not?

Comment: @Guazz Paste into notepad, wrap with html/body, open in browser, set character encoding to UTF-8, I get: Zard Frères Guesta - looks like UTF-8 to me.  So you need to convert the file to UTF-16 (every character 2-bytes) before using BCP and then use the equivalent of the -W option in your BULK INSERT.

Comment: @Guazz Apparently you can use code page 65001 in SQL Server 2005 bcp, but not in 2008: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're using CODEPAGE = 1252 (a single-byte characterset) when you're loading the data in OPENROWSET.

Try using 1202 (UTF-16), or possibly 1208 (UTF-8)

Cheers

Comment: I believe code page 65001 should do the trick.  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001?wa=wsignin1.0